# How to call method inside class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have this button in html:

```
<button id="btnCell" onclick="CellClicked(1, 1, false)"></button>
```

And this Javascript:

```
 $(function() {       
    $( "#txtSearch" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
         //some logic
      },
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id );
        },
    });

  function CellClicked(x, y, selXml) {          
        //some logic
    }        
});
```

Whenever I click button above I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: CellClicked is not defined
```

It happens because the method encapsulated in class, I know that I can drag the method out of the class and it will work.

But I want the method to be encapsulated those I ask the question how can I call the function when method CellClicked  encapsulated?

Comment: Have you tried `$('#btnCell').on('click', ...)`?

Comment: Define `CellClicked` outside the `$(function() { ` in a global scope.

Comment: @gurvinder372 why? just curious

Comment: @ParagJadhav because onclick is not going to magically locate `CellClicked` method otherwise.

Comment: One thing to note, you have no classes in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the listener via Javascript, not via markup. It is more preferable than moving the function into the global scope.

```
 $(function() {       
    $( "#txtSearch" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
         //some logic
      },
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id );
        },
    });

    function CellClicked(x, y, selXml) {          
        //some logic
    }       

    $('#btnCell').on('click', function() {
        CellClicked(1,1,false);
    }) 
});
```

Comment: Should we not mark this as dupe as *how to add click event using jQuery*?

Comment: I don't know. You have downvoted?

Comment: Yes. The answer addresses the problem but in my understanding, correct way is to mark it as dupe and not answer it. So the vote signifies that answer is *not required* and **not** that it is wrong